# Query a key press using ctypes

Tags: python, keyboard-events

I'd like to query each key of a keyboard without using `win32api`. I have it working using `win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(key)`, but I'd also like to add support for if the module is not installed.

So far I've found one piece of fully working code, though it seems a bit heavyweight as it'd require its own thread, and would need over 1600 separate functions as I want to catch each key no matter of modifiers (there are 14 possible combinations per key).

Here is the code I found, would anyone be able to either suggest an alternative or how to get around the modifier problem?

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
import win32con


class GlobalHotKeys(object):
    """
    Register a key using the register() method, or using the @register decorator
    Use listen() to start the message pump

    Example:

    from globalhotkeys import GlobalHotKeys

    @GlobalHotKeys.register(GlobalHotKeys.VK_F1)
    def hello_world():
        print 'Hello World'

    GlobalHotKeys.listen()
    """

    key_mapping = []
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32

    MOD_ALT = win32con.MOD_ALT
    MOD_CTRL = win32con.MOD_CONTROL
    MOD_CONTROL = win32con.MOD_CONTROL
    MOD_SHIFT = win32con.MOD_SHIFT
    MOD_WIN = win32con.MOD_WIN

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, vk, modifier=0, func=None):
        """
        vk is a windows virtual key code
         - can use ord('X') for A-Z, and 0-1 (note uppercase letter only)
         - or win32con.VK_* constants
         - for full list of VKs see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731.aspx

        modifier is a win32con.MOD_* constant

        func is the function to run.  If False then break out of the message loop
        """

        # Called as a decorator?
        if func is None:
            def register_decorator(f):
                cls.register(vk, modifier, f)
                return f
            return register_decorator
        else:
            cls.key_mapping.append((vk, modifier, func))


    @classmethod
    def listen(cls):
        """
        Start the message pump
        """

        for index, (vk, modifiers, func) in enumerate(cls.key_mapping):
            if not cls.user32.RegisterHotKey(None, index, modifiers, vk):
                raise Exception('Unable to register hot key: ' + str(vk) + ' error code is: ' + str(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()))

        try:
            msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
            i = 0

            while cls.user32.GetMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
                if msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:
                    (vk, modifiers, func) = cls.key_mapping[msg.wParam]
                    if not func:
                        break
                    func()

                cls.user32.TranslateMessage(ctypes.byref(msg))
                cls.user32.DispatchMessageA(ctypes.byref(msg))


        finally:
            for index, (vk, modifiers, func) in enumerate(cls.key_mapping):
                cls.user32.UnregisterHotKey(None, index)


    @classmethod
    def _include_defined_vks(cls):
        for item in win32con.__dict__:
            item = str(item)
            if item[:3] == 'VK_':
                setattr(cls, item, win32con.__dict__[item])


    @classmethod
    def _include_alpha_numeric_vks(cls):
        for key_code in (list (range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1)) + list(range(ord('0'), ord('9') + 1)) ):
            setattr(cls, 'VK_' + chr(key_code), key_code)

GlobalHotKeys._include_defined_vks()
GlobalHotKeys._include_alpha_numeric_vks()
```

This is an example of how it'd be used to read `a`:

```
@GlobalHotKeys.register(ord('A'))
def a():
    print 'a'
@GlobalHotKeys.register(ord('A'), GlobalHotKeys.MOD_SHIFT)
def a_shift():
    print 'shift + a'
@GlobalHotKeys.register(ord('A'), GlobalHotKeys.MOD_CONTROL | GlobalHotKeys.MOD_SHIFT)
def a_ctrl_shift():
    print 'ctrl + shift + a'
...

GlobalHotKeys.listen()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be an extremely simple answer, I finally stumbled across it when trying to read the microsoft info for the `GetKeyState` function.

```
ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyState(key)
```

The state will either be 0 or 1 when not pressed, and increase to something like 60000 when pressed, so to get a `True/False` result, checking for `> 1` seems to do the trick.

`GetAsyncKeyState` also kinda works, but sometimes results in a negative number, and sometimes doesn't, so I thought it'd be best using the alternative.